# When uploading an image in admin, get error: File extension 'jpg' is not allowed. Allowed extensions are: ''

Tags: django

I have the following model to upload images:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/img/')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In development I could use the admin page to upload without any issues, but for some reason in production it gives me the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVSxy.png

I'm stumped, especially because I am able to upload it using the following model without any issues in production:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/docs/')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've tried googling the error with no results, and the best I could find was file validation, which I thought was the purpose of using an ImageField in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's worked, If you change your image model like this:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/img/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['jpg'])])
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: That solved the issue, thank you very much!  Any insight into why it needs validators in production but not development, or why the generic FileField doesn't require validators to be specified?  Is this normal behavior for ImageFields?

Comment: I think it depend on your vps, means it has some limitation on some file types. but if you want more inforamation about this, I refer to to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/

Comment: That makes sense, I appreciate your response!  I did vote on your answer and have accepted it, but it said until I have 15 reputation my vote won't affect the public score.  Once again, thank you so much for your help!